How to Generate PDFs with Mixed Hebrew and English Text in .NET 6+?
I need to generate PDFs that support both Hebrew and English text. I've tried using iTextSharp(it is not MIT or Apache license), but I'm encountering issues with rendering mixed language content (Hebrew and English) along with special characters.
Sample Text:
Invoice Date: 2024-07-15
Customer Name: John Doe
Total Cost: $500
Address : DEmo address
תאריך חשבונית: 15-07-2024
שם לקוח: יוחנן דות
סכום כולל: 500$
העיר
2, מבחן

ישראל
00000,
):Address

Current Approach:
Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:
public class PdfGenerator
{
    public void GeneratePdf()
    {
        string filePath = "output.pdf";
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
 
        string fontPath = //fontPath ;
        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font = new Font(baseFont, 12, Font.NORMAL);
 
        string mixedContent = "Invoice Date: 2024-07-15\nCustomer Name: John Doe\nTotal Cost: $500\n\nהודעת חשבונית\nתאריך חשבונית: 15-07-2024\nשם לקוח: יוחנן דות\nסכום כולל: 500$";
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(mixedContent, font);
        document.Add(paragraph);
 
        document.Close();
    }
}
 
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        PdfGenerator pdfGenerator = new PdfGenerator();
        pdfGenerator.GeneratePdf();
    }
}

Issues:
1.The Hebrew text is not rendering correctly.
2.Special characters are not displayed properly.
3.Alignment issues with Right-to-Left (RTL) text.
Question:
How can I correctly render mixed Hebrew and English text in a PDF using iTextSharp or any other free and open-source library with an MIT or Apache license that supports .NET 6+?
Any specific configurations or alternative libraries that handle RTL text better?
What I'm Looking For:
1.A solution to render mixed language text correctly.
2.Handling of special characters.
3.Proper text alignment for RTL languages.

you can use iText/iTextsharp with pdfCalligraph (typography) module to achieve this, but pdfCalligraph is not dual licensed/available with an opensource license.

I have had terrible experience with mixed content in the past and would actually recommend to create 2 docs, one RTL, one LTR and then combine them. If that's feasable for you.

@AndréLemos i checked about  iTextsharp,it showing Deprecated.

@Fildor, is there any other pdf library which is OPEN SOURCE and MIT/APACHE license.which supports Hebrew,English ,Numbers and combination.

I have been using iTextSharp and QuestPDF, only. Dealt with mixed content only in iTextSharp. Cannot tell if others handle it better. I would assume it's a thing that is inherent to the PDF spec/format but that's only a guess.

@Fildor   i checked about iTextsharp,it showing Deprecated

you just need to use iText 8 + pdfCalligraph (people typically recognize iText for .NET as iTextSharp, sorry for the confusion). So this and this.
